# how to draw First Line and Second Line according to UiTextfield on click of UIButton in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

i want to draw line, i have two textfiled in which i enter some value and when i click the button, the line will draw(1cm for each textfiled value)...

suppose i enter some value on line 1 textfiled, the line will draw 1cm and when i enter value 5 the line will draw 5cm...

same as textfiled 2...

when the line of first textfield end , the second textfiled line will start at the end of first textfield line...

Means lastpoint of line 1 is a starting point of line two...

Totally i have two textField and 1 button.

I have no idea how to do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to subclass a `UIView` (`MYDrawingView`)

Add the parameter for drawing as properties of this `MYDrawingView`
Then implement `drawRect` function of `UIView` in `MYDrawingView`, after that you can use the `drawRect` to draw lines and/or other shapes